# Android down loading html file

Tags: android

The html program i down load is on a thread.
I am using this program to down load

```
    try {
        URL data = new URL("http:......../daily.htm");
        URLConnection conexion = data.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(conexion.getInputStream());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        char[] buffer = new char[60000];//4*1024];
        int n = 0;
          while(n >= 0) {
            n = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            if (n > 0) {
                sb.append(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        }
```

My html TEXT is about 46k of data.
ON STARTING THE PROGRAM sometimes the download is incomplete and the data is much less than what I need (46k). It seems like the download is not finished.
However when the program is already running it never fails!!. Only on startup.
Any idea how to debug in such a case. Or can I use a ROCK SOLID another program?